# Select From Array By Id

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 arrays

One is an array that contains every project:

```
let allProjects = [{project_id: 1, name: "project 1"}, {project_id: 2, name: "project 2"}, {project_id: 3, name: "project 3"}, {project_id: 4, name: "project 4"}]
```

And one contains only project ids

```
let selectedProjects = [{project_id: 1}, {project_id: 2}]
```

How can I get the names from allProjects array and return a new array containing name and id according to the Id's that are provided in the selectedProjects array?

Comment: [`Array.prototype.filter()` +] `Array.prototype.map()` + `Array.prototype.find()`

Comment: Two `for` loops would also work, so... What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of `filter`, `map` and `includes`:

```
console.log(allProjects
            .filter(project => selectedProjects
                               .map(p => p.project_id)
                               .includes(project.project_id)));
```

Output:

```
[
  { project_id: 1, name: 'project 1' },
  { project_id: 2, name: 'project 2' }
]
```

Probably there is a way to avoid `map` but for me `map` focuses the intention.